# Get pointers to all fields of a struct dynamically using reflection

Tags: sql, go, reflection, orm, go-reflect

I'm trying to build a simple orm layer for golang.
Which would take a struct and generate the `cols []` which can then be passed to sql function
`rows.Scan(cols...)` which takes pointers of fields in the struct corresponding to each of the columns it has found in the result set

Here is my example struct

```
type ExampleStruct struct {
    ID        int64          `sql:"id"`
    aID    string         `sql:"a_id"`
    UserID    int64          `sql:"user_id"`
```

And this is my generic ORM function

```
func GetSqlColumnToFieldMap(model *ExampleStruct) map[string]interface{} {
    
    typeOfModel := reflect.TypeOf(*model)
    ValueOfModel := reflect.ValueOf(*model)
    columnToDataPointerMap := make(map[string]interface{})
    for i := 0; i < ValueOfModel.NumField(); i++ {
        sql_column := typeOfModel.Field(i).Tag.Get("sql")
        structValue := ValueOfModel.Field(i)
        columnToDataPointerMap[sql_column] = structValue.Addr()
    }
    return columnToDataPointerMap
}
```

Once this method works fine i can use the map it generates to create an ordered list of sql pointers according to the column_names i get in rows() object
However i get below error on the `.Addr()` method call

```
panic: reflect.Value.Addr of unaddressable value [recovered]
    panic: reflect.Value.Addr of unaddressable value
```

Is it not possible to do this ?
Also in an ideal scenario i would want the method to take an interface instead of *ExampleStruct so that it can be reused across different db models.

Comment: I find it helpful to think that in `reflect.ValueOf(*model)` the argument `*model` is passed by value (copied), so the call to `Addr()` later on would take the address of the copy. `reflect.ValueOf(model).Elem()` ensures that `ValueOfModel` is something your program actually has a handle to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says the value whose address you want to get is unaddressable. This is because even though you pass a pointer to `GetSqlColumnToFieldMap()`, you immediately dereference it and work with a non-pointer value later on.

This value is wrapped in an `interface{}` when passed to `reflect.ValueOf()`, and values wrappped in interfaces are not addressable.

You must not dereference the pointer, but instead use `Type.Elem()` and `Value.Elem()` to get the element type and pointed value.

Something like this:

```
func GetSqlColumnToFieldMap(model *ExampleStruct) map[string]interface{} {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(model).Elem()
    v := reflect.ValueOf(model).Elem()
    columnToDataPointerMap := make(map[string]interface{})
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        sql_column := t.Field(i).Tag.Get("sql")
        structValue := v.Field(i)
        columnToDataPointerMap[sql_column] = structValue.Addr()
    }
    return columnToDataPointerMap
}
```

With this simple change it works! And it doesn't depend on the parameter type, you may change it to `interface{}` and pass any struct pointers.

```
func GetSqlColumnToFieldMap(model interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    // ...
}
```

Testing it:

```
type ExampleStruct struct {
    ID     int64  `sql:"id"`
    AID    string `sql:"a_id"`
    UserID int64  `sql:"user_id"`
}

type Point struct {
    X int `sql:"x"`
    Y int `sql:"y"`
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(GetSqlColumnToFieldMap(&ExampleStruct{}))
    fmt.Println(GetSqlColumnToFieldMap(&Point{}))
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/-_fQlsGPZup)):

```
map[a_id:<*string Value> id:<*int64 Value> user_id:<*int64 Value>]
map[x:<*int Value> y:<*int Value>]
```

Note that [`Value.Addr()`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.Addr) returns the address wrapped in a `reflect.Value`. To "unwrap" the pointer, use [`Value.Interface()`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.Interface):

```
func GetSqlColumnToFieldMap(model interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(model).Elem()
    v := reflect.ValueOf(model).Elem()
    m := make(map[string]interface{})
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        colName := t.Field(i).Tag.Get("sql")
        field := v.Field(i)
        m[colName] = field.Addr().Interface()
    }
    return m
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/-4z6JqOo8Ws)):

```
map[a_id:0xc00007e008 id:0xc00007e000 user_id:0xc00007e018]
map[x:0xc000018060 y:0xc000018068]
```

For an in-depth introduction to reflection, please read blog post: [The Laws of Reflection](https://go.dev/blog/laws-of-reflection)

Comment: thanks for the quick, elaborate and on point answer ! This worked like a charm.

Comment: follow up question: I modified the ```GetSqlColumnToFieldMap```function as per your suggestion and it works as long as i pass my models statically; but fails if i try to supply the models generated from reflections ```reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(Point{})).Elem().Interface()```. I've modified the playground link you shared. Please have a look at it

Comment: This `reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(Point{})).Elem().Interface()` creates `Point{}`. The fuction I proposed expects a pointer to a struct, that is `&Point{}`. So using reflection it should be `reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(Point{})).Interface()`